# OpenMP omp_get_num_threads() V.S. omp_get_max_threads()

Tags: c++, openmp

I do not understand the difference between omp_get_num_threads() and omp_get_max_threads(). I copy the demo code as the following.

```
    omp_set_nested(1);
    omp_set_max_active_levels(10);
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        omp_set_num_threads(3);

        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            omp_set_num_threads(4);
            #pragma omp single
            {
                std::cout << omp_get_max_active_levels() << " " << omp_get_num_threads() << " " 
                << omp_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
            }
        }

        #pragma omp barrier
        #pragma omp single 
        {
            std::cout << omp_get_max_active_levels() << " " << omp_get_num_threads() << " " 
                << omp_get_max_threads() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

And then I got the following output.

```
10 3 4
10 3 4
10 3 4
10 3 3
```

I have checked the official documentation, but I am still confused about that.

Comment: This output does not seen to be correct. What is your compiler? An correct output would be: 10 3 4 - 10 3 4 - 10 2 3

Comment: @648trindade I use the g++ compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From documentation:

`omp_get_num_threads`

> The `omp_get_num_threads` routine returns the number of threads in the team executing the `parallel` region to which the routine region binds. If called from the sequential part of a program, this routine returns 1.

`omp_get_max_threads`

> The value returned by `omp_get_max_threads` is the value of the first element of the *nthreads-var* ICV of the current task. This value is also an upper bound on the number of threads that could be used to form a new team if a parallel region without a `num_threads`clause were encountered after execution returns from this routine.

The figure below illustrates the flow of threads. Your output may be incorrect, and I can't reproduce it with clang+libomp or gcc+libGOMP.

[image]

The `omp_get_max_threads` always returns the number of threads that a new `parallel` construct can create, if the number of threads is not specified along with it. When you set 4 on `omp_set_num_threads` at inner parallel region, the maximum number of new different threads that can be created is 4, but in that region 3 are in use. For the outer parallel region, the max is 3, and 2 are in use.

In a serial code, out of any pragmas, the number of threads is 1, but the max is the default for the system (usually the number of cores), if you not changed it via `omp_set_num_threads` or `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable